# Как сделать div одинаковой ширины в линию , если есть внешние отступы?

Tags: css, html, width

В случае, когда нет отступов, все решается достаточно просто - задаем ширину в процентах и все отлично, все блоки в линию Но что, если вдруг нужно сделать отступы между div?

Пример:
CSS

```
   .wide{
       width: 100%; 
       background: yellow;
    }

    *{ box-sizing: border-box; }

    .someContent{ 
      float: left;
      width: 25%; height: 50px;
      background: gray;
      border: 2px solid black; 
    }

    .wrapper{ 
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;  
      width: 70%;
      border: 2px dotted green;
    }

        .wrapper::after{
          content:"";
          clear: both;
          display: table;  
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="wide">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="someContent">Контент</div>
    <div class="someContent">Контент</div>
    <div class="someContent">Контент</div>
    <div class="someContent">Контент</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если в данном примере задать width в процентах у .someContent то последний блок перенесется.

Как реализовать отступы между блоками чтобы сохранилась ровная линия и относительная одинаковая ширина каждого блока?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отступы тоже в процентах попробуйте:

```
.someContent{ 
  width: 23%;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
```

ДЕМО https://jsfiddle.net/mg9wh3oa/

Comment: Мысль вашу понял, но мне кажется, что заниматься перебором значений - не очень хорошая практика, плюс иногда важно чтобы отступ был все таки фиксированного размера. Способ рабочий, но думается мне, не единственный.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать calc()

Что-то типа

```
width: calc(25% - 15px);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMPamL